# Reading .docx and .pdf file using pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, pdf, plsql, docx

I want to read .docx and .pdf files stored in local disk using PL/SQL. And I want to extract some of data like Name,contact,email address from the .docx or .pdf files.

All this using PL/SQL.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i dont know if you can do it with a doc file, you should try to get your input from plain text file.

Comment: And for plain text what shoul I do ? @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Oracle Text supports MS Office and PDF formats.  No need for plain text

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has a product which handles free text, Oracle Text.  This can deal with common binary formats: you should be alright with Word and PDF.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/toc.htm).

Text supports searching of documents with different index types for various use cases.  However, like normal indexes they are really suited to equality searches.  That is we can search a document for a *specific email* like this:

```
select * from t23
where contains(col_t, 'muhammad.hannan@example.com') > 0
/
```

But it's not very helpful when it comes to extracting all email addresses from a document.  That's why we Nature gave us tools for defining structured documents (XML, JSON).    So how well Text will support your actual use case depends on the details which you haven't posted.

---

Your question says 'local files'.  Oracle Text will [work with BFILEs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cdatadic.htm#CCREF1903), that is externally stored files. Define the table column with the BFILE datatype.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_working.htm#ADLOB002)

However, BFILEs must be held in OS directories on the database server (i.e. local to the database not your PC), which are subject to the expected security permissions.  Find out about [creating Directories here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5007.htm#SQLRF01207).

Comment: Thanks for your contribution . I have `resume file` in either `docx or pdf format` and I want to extract some of basic information like `name, contact, email, adress and education`. @APC

Comment: What should I do for files stored in database server? @APC

Comment: I have clarified my answer by adding link to documentation for BFILE data type.